# When i run python manage.py runserver(django 3.1) it returns NoReverseMatch at /

Tags: python, templates, django-templates, rendering

After setting up urls.py file in both project and app and templates in templates folder in the app(learing_logs) directory. I run python manage.py in terminal it shows following error in my web browser

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\learning_logs\templates\learning_logs\base.html, error at line 2
   'learning_logs' is not a registered namespace
   1 : <p>
   2 :     <a href=" {% url 'learning_logs:index' %} ">Learning Log</a>
   3 :     <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
   4 : </p>
   5 : 
   6 : {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 72, in reverse
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]

During handling of the above exception ('learning_logs'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\learning_logs\views.py", line 8, in index
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\athithi\Documents\VirtualEnvironmentWork\11_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 83, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: 'learning_logs' is not a registered namespace
```

urls.py in project(learning_log)

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

urls.py in app(learning_logs)
"""Defines URL patterns for learning_logs."""

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    # Show all topics.
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
]
```

Comment: Show us the `urls.py` file.

Comment: How/where have you registered the `learning_logs` namespace?